# Can't insert DECIMAL values into my table MYSQL. ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE

Tags: mysql

So, I've ran into this issue where I created a table, and added a "student_grade" column for type DECIMAL values:

```
CREATE TABLE relationship (
    teacher_id INT,
    student_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(teacher_id, student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher(teacher_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES student(student_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
ALTER TABLE relationship ADD COLUMN student_grade DECIMAL(4, 4);
```

And after that I inserted the values:

```
INSERT INTO relationship VALUES(100, 400, 5.5);
INSERT INTO relationship VALUES(101, 401, 8.2);
INSERT INTO relationship VALUES(102, 402, 6.3);
INSERT INTO relationship VALUES(102, 403, 10);
INSERT INTO relationship VALUES(101, 404, 9.1);
INSERT INTO relationship VALUES(100, 405, 4.4);
```

Inserting any of these values gives an error:

> Error: Out of range value for column 'student_grade' at row 1
> Error Code: ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE

I recreated an ran this in new queries, but it still doesn't work.
Maybe i'm missing something, anyone have any ideas?

P.S. It lets me add integer values so if I change the table's column type from DECIMAL to INT and insert an INT value it works, but for this I need DECIMAL or FLOAT values.

Comment: Look up what `DECIMAL(4, 4)` will actually allow

Comment: If you are having problems [There is always the MySQL Manual to refer to in an absolute emergency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `(4,4)` says 4 total digits of precision, with 4 digits after the decimal point.  So you only can use values 0.0000 through 0.9999 (or negative).  Try `(10,4)` or similar.